# No Type Error when trying to transform JSON to AVRO

Tags: avro, dataweave, mulesoft

I'm trying to convert a JSON payload to Avro to publish to a Kafka topic. However, when I do the Dataweave transformation I'm getting a "No Type" error.  I'm not sure what's causing the error.  I originally thought this might be due to the transformation not knowing what the MIME type on the inbound payload.  So, I've made sure that it's set to `application/json` but that didn't make any difference.

Avro Schema

```
{
  "compatibility" : "forward",
  "name": "ContentManagerCoupons",
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "com.rentpath",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "clientID",
      "type": "string"
    },
{
  "name": "outputHistoryId",
  "type": "string"
},
{
  "name": "categoryCoupons",
  "type": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "name": "categoryCoupons_record",
      "type": "record",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "applyBy",
          "type": [
            "string",
            "int",
            "null"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "applyPeriod",
          "type": [
            "string",
            "null"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "cashValue",
          "type": [
            "int",
            "null"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "couponCategory",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "cashOffDesc",
          "type": [
            "string",
            "null"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "endDate",
          "type": [
            "string",
            "null"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "feeType",
          "type": [
            "string",
            "null"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "freeWeeks",
          "type": [
            "string",
            "null"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "generatedText",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "leaseby",
          "type": [
            "string",
            "null"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "leaseTerm",
          "type": [
            "int",
            "null"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "offerText",
          "type": [
            "string",
            "null"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "startDate",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "unitType",
          "type": [
            "string",
            "null"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
]
}
```

JSON Message

```
{
"outputHistoryId": "55324456",
"clientID": "112345",
"categoryCoupons": [
    {
        "unitType": null,
        "startDate": "07/21/2020",
        "offerText": "This would be the special offer message.",
        "leaseTerm": null,
        "leaseby": null,
        "generatedText": "This would be the special offer message..",
        "freeWeeks": null,
        "feeType": null,
        "endDate": "10/01/2020",
        "couponCategory": "Special Offer",
        "cashValue": null,
        "cashOffDesc": null,
        "applyPeriod": null,
        "applyBy": null
    }
]
}
```

Datawave

```
%dw 2.2
output application/avro schemaUrl="http://schema-registry.domain.com:8081/subjects/Coupon-value/versions/1"
---
payload
```

Error Message

> "org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException - No type: {"subject":"ContentManager.Coupon-value","version":1,"id":342,"schema":"{"type":"record","name":"ContentManagerCoupons","namespace":"com.rentpath","fields":[{"name":"clientID","type":"string"},{"name":"outputHistoryId","type":"string"},{"name":"categoryCoupons","type":{"type":"array","items":{"type":"record","name":"categoryCoupons_record","fields":[{"name":"applyBy","type":["string","int","null"]},{"name":"applyPeriod","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"cashValue","type":["int","null"]},{"name":"couponCategory","type":"string"},{"name":"cashOffDesc","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"endDate","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"feeType","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"freeWeeks","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"generatedText","type":"string"},{"name":"leaseby","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"leaseTerm","type":["int","null"]},{"name":"offerText","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"startDate","type":"string"},{"name":"unitType","type":["string","null"]}]}}}],"compatibility":"forward"}"}
> org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: No type: {"subject":"ContentManager.Coupon-value","version":1,"id":342,"schema":"{"type":"record","name":"ContentManagerCoupons","namespace":"com.rentpath","fields":[{"name":"clientID","type":"string"},{"name":"outputHistoryId","type":"string"},{"name":"categoryCoupons","type":{"type":"array","items":{"type":"record","name":"categoryCoupons_record","fields":[{"name":"applyBy","type":["string","int","null"]},{"name":"applyPeriod","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"cashValue","type":["int","null"]},{"name":"couponCategory","type":"string"},{"name":"cashOffDesc","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"endDate","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"feeType","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"freeWeeks","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"generatedText","type":"string"},{"name":"leaseby","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"leaseTerm","type":["int","null"]},{"name":"offerText","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"startDate","type":"string"},{"name":"unitType","type":["string","null"]}]}}}],"compatibility":"forward"}"}
> at org.apache.avro.Schema.getRequiredText(Schema.java:1753)
> at org.apache.avro.Schema.parse(Schema.java:1604)
> at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:1394)
> at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:1365)
> at org.mule.weave.v2.module.avro.AvroWriter.doWriteValue(AvroWriter.scala:195)
> at org.mule.weave.v2.module.writer.Writer.writeValue(Writer.scala:41)
> at org.mule.weave.v2.module.writer.Writer.writeValue$(Writer.scala:39)
> at org.mule.weave.v2.module.avro.AvroWriter.writeValue(AvroWriter.scala:44)
> at org.mule.weave.v2.module.writer.DeferredWriter.doWriteValue(DeferredWriter.scala:73)
> at org.mule.weave.v2.module.writer.Writer.writeValue(Writer.scala:41)
> at org.mule.weave.v2.module.writer.Writer.writeValue$(Writer.scala:39)
> at org.mule.weave.v2.module.writer.DeferredWriter.writeValue(DeferredWriter.scala:16)
> at org.mule.weave.v2.module.writer.WriterHelper$.writeValue(Writer.scala:120)
> at org.mule.weave.v2.module.writer.WriterHelper$.writeAndGetResult(Writer.scala:98)
> at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.InterpretedMappingExecutableWeave.write(InterpreterMappingCompilerPhase.scala:236)
> at org.mule.weave.v2.el.WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.evaluateWithTimeout(WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.scala:243)
> at org.mule.weave.v2.el.WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.evaluate(WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.scala:108)
> at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.el.dataweave.DataWeaveExpressionLanguageAdaptor$1.evaluate(DataWeaveExpressionLanguageAdaptor.java:308)
> at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.el.DefaultExpressionManagerSession.evaluate(DefaultExpressionManagerSession.java:105)
> at com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.SetPayloadTransformationTarget.process(SetPayloadTransformationTarget.java:32)
> at com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.TransformMessageProcessor.lambda$0(TransformMessageProcessor.java:92)
> at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
> at com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.TransformMessageProcessor.process(TransformMessageProcessor.java:92)
> at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.func.CheckedFunction.apply(CheckedFunction.java:25)
> at org.mule.runtime.core.api.rx.Exceptions.lambda$checkedFunction$2(Exceptions.java:84)
> at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.util.rx.Operators.lambda$nullSafeMap$0(Operators.java:47)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandleFuseable.java:165)
> at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$2.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:425)
> at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$2.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:420)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:127)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:345)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnValue$ScheduledScalar.run(FluxSubscribeOnValue.java:178)
> at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:50)
> at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:27)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:111)
> at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.RunnableFutureDecorator.run(RunnableFutureDecorator.java:54)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748), while writing Avro at payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the answer is pretty simple.  I just needed to add `schema` to the end of my URL.  This removes the extraneous items like version and id that come down without it.

**New Dataweave**

```
%dw 2.2
output application/avro schemaUrl="http://schema-registry.domain.com:8081/subjects/Coupon-value/versions/1/schema"
---
payload
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work for me. Maybe there is a problem trying to access the schema. Because I don't have access to that URL I replaced it with a local file:

```
output application/avro schemaUrl="classpath://schema.json"
```

Comment: It works for me as well, if I use a local file.  However, that adds the schema to the Avro message and the  person trying to consume the message is looking for the referee to the Schema Registry, instead.

Comment: it's not an access issue either.  I can see the schema in the error message